# Infinty loop in constuctor - Creating the same istances of related objects

Tags: php, php-7.4

I got stuck in an endless loop creating the same objects over and over in the models.

But from the beginning:

I have two related models, lets call `A` and `B`

`A` could has many `B` and `B` belongs to one `A`.

And since model `B` refers to the fields of `A`, I added it as protected property to avoid creating new object when calling `B` method related with `A` fields.

The constuctor of `B` looks like:

```
public function __construct(int $id = null)
{
    parent::__construct($id);

    $a = $this->get('a_id'); 
    if ($a) {
        $this->a = new A($a);
    }
}
```

and `A`:

```
public function __construct(int $id = null)
{
    parent::__construct($id);

    $this->date = new CarbonPL($this->get('date'));
    $this->initB();
}
```

But then I realized that calling initB() creates again the same instance o B with creating the same A and so on forever

```
private function initB()
{
    if (!$this->isReferenced()) { // Checks wheter is instance exists in DB
        return;
    }
    $query = B::getIDQuery();
    $query .= ' WHERE is_del IS FALSE';
    $query .= ' AND a_id = ' . $this->id;

    $ids = Helper::queryIds($query);

    foreach ($ids as $id) {
        $this->B[] = new B($id);
    }
}
```

I need that object of A contains loaded of B and vice verse, because a lot of B refer to A field and vice versa, but how to prevent yourself from such an endless loop.

I quickly got the idea of an extra parameter in `B` which would be `A`, and if it were, I wouldn't have to reuse the constuctor. But I don't really like this solution because of the second parameter and I was wondering how to solve it in a different (better) way, preferably so that you can still only enter the identifier.

`B` conctructor after that fix:

```
public function __construct(int $id = null, A $a = null)
{
    parent::__construct($id);

    if ($a) {
        $this->a = $a;
    } else {
        $a = $this->geti('a_id');
        if ($a) {
            $this->a = new A($a);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is the second parameter a problem?  It sounds like you found a solution to your original problem but there's something about the solution you don't like.  I just don't understand what it is you don't like about it.  There's nothing wrong with having a second parameter, is there?

Comment: To tell you the truth, that's what I wanted to know. Somehow internally, it doesn't seem like a good idea. What if I had 10 other dependent models in this model, I don't think passing all in the constructor would be a good idea

Comment: But this situation happens because these two classes have a 1-to-many relationship between them.  It seems unlikely that you'd have a class with 10 different 1-to-many relationships, although it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the 2 parameter solution you came up with but if you're looking for another option...

One way to deal with this is to create a cache of instances for each class so that when someone needs an instance of your class they don't call `new()` they call a factory method that will construct a new instance only if there is not one already in the cache with the ID.

```
<?php

class A {
    private static $cache = array();
    
    private function __construct( $id ) {
        // A private constructor prevents any other class from creating new instances
        // It could be protected if you want to allow subclasses to call new A()
        parent::__construct( $id );
        $this->date = new CarbonPL($this->get('date'));
        $this->initB();
    }
    
    public static function create_for_id( $id ) {
        if ( isset( self::$cache[ $id ] ) ) {
            $result = self::$cache[ $id ];
        } else {
            $result = new A( $id );
            self::$cache[ $id ] = $result; // Save it for later reuse
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

In class B you can do the same thing or however it will work best for your situation.
Now in your B constructor (or anywhere you want a new A) rather than calling `new A($id)` you will call `A::create_for_id( $id )`.  If an A with that ID already exists then it will reuse it rather than constructing endless new instances.

Comment: I just implemented such a solution, it seems much better than the one I had before.
Overall, I think loading objects via construct is a bad idea, but too many models in my project rely on this approach, in the future it will change according to what I did for that model now - Model::getInstance(int $id) - is based on the same premise as yours. Thank you